# Java 8 U172 crashes, easylogging++

Tags: easylogging++

We have 3 java thread calling native code where easylogging++ framework is used for logging. The app threads run for a while until the JVM crash happens. This is on a Windows 10 64 Bit PC using Java 8 U172. it happens every 30 minutes.

Below is the hs_err_pid5052 created.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffe1a71e02d, pid=5052, tid=0x0000000000001ea4
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_172-b11) (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.172-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [iSerial.dll+0xe02d]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000001eb25000):  JavaThread "Device Id: 11 Device Name : BLOCK" [_thread_in_native, id=7844, stack(0x000000002be30000,0x000000002bf30000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xffffffffffffffff

Registers:
RAX=0x000000002934a3a0, RBX=0x0000000027cdcf08, RCX=0x453d0f35522ec1dd, RDX=0x000000002934a3a0
RSP=0x000000002bf2e740, RBP=0x000000002bf2efc0, RSI=0x000000002bf2eb90, RDI=0x000000002bf2eb80
R8 =0x453d0f35522ec1dd, R9 =0x0000000000d599a8, R10=0x0000000029354d40, R11=0x0000000000000000
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000027cdcf08, R14=0x000000002bf2f040, R15=0x000000001eb25000
RIP=0x00007ffe1a71e02d, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000002bf2e740)
0x000000002bf2e740:   0000000000d59990 000000002934a3a0
0x000000002bf2e750:   0000000000000000 00007ffe1a71d31f
0x000000002bf2e760:   0000000000d59990 000000002934a3a0
0x000000002bf2e770:   453d0f35522ec1dd 000000002934a3a0
0x000000002bf2e780:   0000000000000000 0000000000000080
0x000000002bf2e790:   000000002bf2efc0 00007ffe1a71e4d4
0x000000002bf2e7a0:   0000000000d59990 000000002934a3a0
0x000000002bf2e7b0:   453d0f35522ec1dd 0000000000000000
0x000000002bf2e7c0:   000000002934a390 453d0f35522ec1cd
0x000000002bf2e7d0:   000000002934a1b0 0000000029395700
0x000000002bf2e7e0:   000000000000003b 0000000000d68ac0
0x000000002bf2e7f0:   0000000029395708 000000002934a3a0
0x000000002bf2e800:   0000000000000015 0000000000d59990
0x000000002bf2e810:   0000000000000001 0800000000000000
0x000000002bf2e820:   0000000000000001 000000002bf2e850
0x000000002bf2e830:   0000000000d59990 00007ffe1a71ed73 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007ffe1a71e02d)
0x00007ffe1a71e00d:   cc cc cc 4c 89 44 24 18 48 89 54 24 10 48 89 4c
0x00007ffe1a71e01d:   24 08 48 83 ec 18 48 8b 44 24 28 48 8b 4c 24 30
0x00007ffe1a71e02d:   8b 09 39 08 75 09 c7 04 24 01 00 00 00 eb 07 c7
0x00007ffe1a71e03d:   04 24 00 00 00 00 0f b6 04 24 48 83 c4 18 c3 cc 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x000000002934a3a0 is an unknown value
RBX={method} {0x0000000027cdcf10} 'open' '(Ljava/lang/String;IBCBCCCCCCI)I' in 'com/hctsi/comm/Serial'
RCX=0x453d0f35522ec1dd is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000002934a3a0 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000002bf2e740 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001eb25000
RBP=0x000000002bf2efc0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001eb25000
RSI=0x000000002bf2eb90 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001eb25000
RDI=0x000000002bf2eb80 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001eb25000
R8 =0x453d0f35522ec1dd is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000d599a8 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000029354d40 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13={method} {0x0000000027cdcf10} 'open' '(Ljava/lang/String;IBCBCCCCCCI)I' in 'com/hctsi/comm/Serial'
R14=0x000000002bf2f040 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001eb25000
R15=0x000000001eb25000 is a thread


Stack: [0x000000002be30000,0x000000002bf30000],  sp=0x000000002bf2e740,  free space=1017k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [iSerial.dll+0xe02d]
C  [iSerial.dll+0xd31f]
C  [iSerial.dll+0xe4d4]
C  [iSerial.dll+0x18ee6]
C  [iSerial.dll+0x15099]
C  [iSerial.dll+0xfddf]
C  [iSerial.dll+0x3575]
C  [iSerial.dll+0x1f63b]
C  [iSerial.dll+0x1d7bb]
C  [iSerial.dll+0x1b6cb]
C  [iSerial.dll+0x176ba]
C  [iSerial.dll+0x3f5f]
C  [iSerial.dll+0x2da30]
C  [iSerial.dll+0x2ab7f]
C  [iSerial.dll+0x2ae1d]
C  [iSerial.dll+0x23749]
C  [iSerial.dll+0x2370d]
C  [iSerial.dll+0x2eb74]
C  [iSerial.dll+0x2e730]
C  0x0000000002d98c67
```

Every Thread checks execute the below logic every 30 seconds. I suspect this is where the issue happens.

```
void StartLog()
{
    el::Configurations conf("C:\\logs\\iserial-conf.conf");
    el::Loggers::reconfigureAllLoggers(conf);
    logger = el::Loggers::getLogger("default");
    el::Helpers::installPreRollOutCallback(renameLogFile);
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a **complete** example.  There's no way anyone can do anything but guess at the cause of the crash given the lack of data.  Note, however, the JNI is **very** fragile - you have to check **every** call to a Java function for success, and you also have to check after **every** such call for pending Java exceptions.  Any programmer who looks at JNI code without error and exception checking and says, "I don't need to check that, it will never fail" should never be allowed to write or touch JNI code.

Comment: The entire stack trace is native code. Get debugging symbols for iSerial.dll and attach a native debugger.